# where it is stored items (video) the in-app Purchase?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, intel, intel-xdk

I am creating a video application using Intel XDK, the first video will be free, others will be paid!

They will pay for the apple and there the videos will be released.

I wonder where the videos are stored in the apple or have to get a server?

and would also like to how this purchase, life cycle, if someone can help me with this, I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple's in-app purchase system only provides the purchase mechanism, it does not store your content for you.

> You can embed that content in your app’s bundle or you can download it as needed
>   https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/DeliverProduct.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH5-SW3